# ASP.net boundcolumn to display products, each month of the year

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I will try to quickly explain my issue and provide the data necessary to hopefully get some help on this issue...  Here is what I am trying to build in ASP.net:

[image: attempted form]

It's basically just a listing of products and the quantities sold each month...  So far, I have figured out how to use asp.net and its "BoundField" property to create the first record:

[image: databound from asp.net]

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT year, product_id, t.id AS id, 
 t.standardcase AS standardcase,
 p.shortname AS shortname 
 FROM transactions t, products p 
 WHERE year = 2009 AND product_id = p.ID AND market_id = 1 AND product_id = 1"
```

and my table structure looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[products](     
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,  
    [shortname] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [SKU] [varchar](50) NULL,   
    [ml] [smallint] NOT NULL,   
    [category]
    [varchar](50) NOT NULL,     
    [status] [bit] NOT NULL)

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transactions](     
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [market_id] [int] NOT NULL,     
    [product_id] [int] NOT NULL,    
    [month] [tinyint] NOT NULL,     
    [year] [smallint] NOT NULL,     
    [standardcase] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [ninelitercase] [int] NOT NULL,     
    [userid] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [timestamp] [nchar](10) NULL)
```

So, for a given year, there are 120 quantities that need to be displayed/edited...

Here is the code I am using for the databound:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<html>
  <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Updating Data Using GridView</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowSorting="false" AllowPaging="false" Runat="server"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" DataKeyNames="id"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Products" DataField="shortname" SortExpression="shortname" />

            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="January" DataField="standardcase" SortExpression="standardcase" />            
        </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" Runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT year, product_id, t.id as id, t.standardcase as standardcase, p.shortname as shortname from transactions t, products p where year = 2009 and product_id = p.ID and market_id = 1 and product_id = 1 and month = 1"
        UpdateCommand=""
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone shed some light on how to use the BoundField to "build" the months across the top?  Each field has a unique ID to make updating easy, but I just need to figure out how in ASP.net to populate the rest of the fields easily?

Comment: try looking at these examples: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that's where I got the initial BoundField functionality from...  The difference with my situation is I don't have separate "columns" for each BoundField...  I essentially have one set of records that I'm trying to span over a twelve month period...

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you update this? If you have for example 10 transactions in January 2009 for a given product, this would equate to 10 records in the transaction table, if the user changes this to 9 which of the 10 records should be deleted? I don't think you can display a summary, and also make it updateable.

Comment: Hi Gareth, there's a one to one relationship between quantities and uniqueIDs...  Each transaction has a unique record that just keeps getting updated...  For example, if you look at the top chart, FRSB for January 2009 has a transaction.id of 1...  so the update statement will always update that one record...  Does that make sense?  As a default, all the quantities have been set to zero...  So obviously when the form first pulls up, all the fields should be 0.